# How can I avoid "Expresion.Error: The column "xxxxxx" of the table wasn't found" in the sample file in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, m

I am working with a data loader in Power Query,
all data to be processed is taken from multiple .xlsx files in a folder.
The problem I have is that, although the columns always have the same header, they are never the same number, so the example file that Power Query takes (the one in the first position in the folder).

[Expresion.Error: The column "xxxxxx" of the table wasn't found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWxY9.png)

To get around this it occurs to me that I could set a default empty table with all possible columns and have the process work from there.

How can I do this?

The Sample Table must be the follow:

```
    SampleFile= #table({"Pronombre", "Información Personal (Prefijo)", "Información Personal (Nombre)", "Información Personal (Segundo nombre)","Información Personal (Apellidos)","Información Personal (Sufijo)", "Email", "DNI", "Cód. Área Telefónico", "Teléfono", "Monto Donación", "Otro monto", "Forma de Pago", "CBU", "Tarjeta", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Mes Vto.", "Año Vto.", "DATOS DE ENVÍO", "Dirección", "Piso y Departamento", "Barrio", "Código Postal", "Ciudad", "Provincia", "¿Cómo llegaste?", "Pronombre_1", "Campaign Source", "Campaign Medium", "Campaign Name", "Campaign Term", "Campaign Content", "Creada por (ID de usuario)", "ID Entrada", "Fecha entrada", "Fecha de actualización", "URL de origen", "ID de transacción", "Cantidad del pago", "Fecha de pago", "Estado del pago", "Id de entrada", "Agente de usuario", "IP del usuario", "ID de la entrada parcial", "ProgresoProgreso: campos obligatorios", "Puntuación de reCAPTCHA"}, {})
```

The code for "Sample File" is as follows:

```
let
    DigitalPath= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    Origen = Folder.Files(DigitalPath),
    Navegación1 = Origen{0}[Content]
in
    Navegación1
```

The code for "Transform sample file" is:

```
let
    Origen = Excel.Workbook(Parámetro6, null, true),
    #"basico-en-2-pasos-marzo-2020-20_Sheet" = Origen{0}[Data],
    #"Encabezados promovidos" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"basico-en-2-pasos-marzo-2020-20_Sheet", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Encabezados promovidos"
```

The process code is:

```
let
       EmptyTable = #table({"Source.Name", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Email","N_de_Documento__c","MobilePhone", "Tipo de Tarjeta","MailingStreet", "MailingPostalCode",  "MailingCity", "Provincia","Descripci_n_Fuente__c","Medio_Campa_a__c", "Campaña","Contenido_Campa_a__c", "ID Entrada", "Fecha_Ingreso__c","Numero de Tarjeta","Monto_Donacion__c","Vencimiento__c","Fuente__c"}, {}),
    DigitalPath= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    Origen = try Table.Buffer(Folder.Files(DigitalPath)) otherwise #table({"Empty table" }, {}),
    result = if Table.IsEmpty(Origen) then EmptyTable else (
let
    #"Archivos ocultos filtrados1" = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invocar función personalizada1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Archivos ocultos filtrados1", "Transformar archivo (6)", each #"Transformar archivo (6)"([Content])),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invocar función personalizada1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Otras columnas quitadas1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado1", {"Source.Name", "Transformar archivo (6)"}),
    #"Columna de tabla expandida1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Otras columnas quitadas1", "Transformar archivo (6)", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transformar archivo (6)"(#"Archivo de ejemplo (6)"))),
    #"Numero de tarjeta1" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columna de tabla expandida1", {{"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}, {"Column19", type text}, {"Column21", type text}, {"Column22", type text}, {"Column23", type text}, {"Column24", type text}, {"Column25", type text}, {"Column26", type text}, {"Column27", type text}}, "es-AR"),{"Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"N° de Tarjeta"),
    #"Numero de Tarjeta" = Table.AddColumn(#"Numero de tarjeta1", "Numero de Tarjeta", each Text.Combine({[CBU], [#"N° de Tarjeta"]}, ""), type text),
    #"Valor reemplazado1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Numero de Tarjeta"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Numero de Tarjeta"}),
    #"Valor reemplazado2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Valor reemplazado1","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Numero de Tarjeta"}),
    #"Tipo cambiado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor reemplazado2",{{"Otro monto", type text}, {"Teléfono", type text}, {"Cód. Área Telefónico", type text}, {"Piso y Departamento", type text}, {"Dirección", type text}}),
    MailingStreet = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo cambiado", "MailingStreet", each [Dirección]& " " &[Piso y Departamento]),
    Monto_Donacion__c = Table.AddColumn(MailingStreet, "Monto_Donacion__c", each if [Monto Donación] = "Quiero donar otro monto" then Text.Select([Otro monto], {"0".."9"}) else [Monto Donación]),
    #"Mes de Vencimiento" = Table.AddColumn(Monto_Donacion__c, "Personalizado", each if [#"Mes Vto."] = null and [#"Año Vto."] = null then null else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Diciembre" then 12 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Noviembre" then 11 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Octubre" then 10 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Enero" then 1 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Febrero" then 2 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Marzo" then 3 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Abril" then 4 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Mayo" then 5 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Junio" then 6 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Julio" then 7 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Agosto" then 8 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Septiembre" then 9 else if [#"Mes Vto."] = "Setiembre" then 9 else null),
    #"Últimos caracteres insertados" = Table.AddColumn(#"Mes de Vencimiento", "Últimos caracteres", each Text.End(Text.From([#"Año Vto."], "es-AR"), 2), type text),
    #"Tipo cambiado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Últimos caracteres insertados",{{"Últimos caracteres", Int64.Type}, {"Código Postal", type text}}),
    Vencimiento__c = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo cambiado2", "Vencimiento__c", each if [#"Mes Vto."] <> null then "28/"&Number.ToText([Personalizado])&"/"&Number.ToText([Últimos caracteres]) else null),
    #"Valor reemplazado3" = Table.ReplaceValue(Vencimiento__c,"-","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Cód. Área Telefónico", "Teléfono"}),
    #"Valor reemplazado4" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Valor reemplazado3"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Cód. Área Telefónico", "Teléfono"}),
    #"Personalizada agregada3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Valor reemplazado4", "Remove 15", each if Text.StartsWith([Teléfono], "15") = true then Text.AfterDelimiter([Teléfono], "15") else [Teléfono]),
    #"Columnas combinadas" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Personalizada agregada3",{"Cód. Área Telefónico", "Remove 15"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"MobilePhone"),
    Fuente__c = Table.AddColumn(#"Columnas combinadas", "Fuente__c", each if [ID Entrada]<>null then [ID Entrada] else "Web"),
    #"Valor reemplazado" = Table.ReplaceValue(Fuente__c," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Numero de Tarjeta"}),
    #"Personalizada agregada" = Table.AddColumn(#"Valor reemplazado", "MailingPostalCode", each Text.Remove([Código Postal], {"A".."z"})),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Personalizada agregada",{{"Información Personal (Nombre)", "Nombre"}, {"Información Personal (Apellidos)", "Apellido"}, {"Tarjeta", "Tipo de Tarjeta"}, {"Ciudad", "MailingCity"}, {"Provincia", "Provincia"}, {"Campaign Medium", "Medio_Campa_a__c"}, {"Campaign Name", "Campaña"}, {"Campaign Content", "Contenido_Campa_a__c"}, {"Fecha entrada", "Fecha_Ingreso__c"}, {"Campaign Source", "Descripci_n_Fuente__c"}}),
    #"Tipo cambiado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado",{{"Vencimiento__c", type date}, {"Fecha_Ingreso__c", type date}, {"MailingPostalCode", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Columnas quitadas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Tipo cambiado1",{"Monto Donación", "Otro monto", "Forma de Pago", "DATOS DE ENVÍO", "Barrio", "¿Cómo llegaste?", "Página / URL de Origen", "Campaign Term", "Mes Vto.", "Información Personal (Prefijo)", "Información Personal (Segundo nombre)", "Información Personal (Sufijo)", "CBU", "Año Vto.", "Creada por (ID de usuario)", "Personalizado", "Últimos caracteres", "N° de Tarjeta", "Column47", "Column48", "Column49", "Column50", "Column51", "Column52", "Column53", "Column54", "Column55", "Teléfono", "Dirección", "Piso y Departamento", "Código Postal"})
in
    #"Columnas quitadas"
)
in
    result
```

I've been trying to create the following table in both "Sample File" and "Transform Sample File":

```
EmptyTable = #table({"Source.Name", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Email","N_de_Documento__c","MobilePhone", "Tipo de Tarjeta","MailingStreet", "MailingPostalCode",  "MailingCity", "Provincia","Descripci_n_Fuente__c","Medio_Campa_a__c", "Campaña","Contenido_Campa_a__c", "ID Entrada", "Fecha_Ingreso__c","Numero de Tarjeta","Monto_Donacion__c","Vencimiento__c","Fuente__c"}, {}),
```

And call it from the "Source" but it doesn't works.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to combine all the files in a directory, even if they have different columns headers per file?

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: No, I'll give you some context that could help:
The database is a Wordpress form which I download every month in mutiples Excels files (.xlsx). All the files has the same headers.
The amount of columns that file has depends on the entries of that month, for example:

In Jan I downloaded one file and goes from columns "A" to "AY", 
on Feb has columns from "A" to "BA", on Mar from "A" to "BH".

I think that if I can standarize the maximum possible columns in the "Sample File" or "Transform Sample File" and work from there. Am I wrong?

I'm absolutly open to others options!

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure of the issue. Code provided works on different amount of columns per file. Did you try it ?

Comment: I tried your code suggestion but it didn't work, I've been trying adding an Try...Otherwise in 

let
    DigitalPath= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    Origen = Folder.Files(DigitalPath),
    Navegación1 = Origen{0}[Content]
in
    Navegación1

but i couldn't make it work.... Any other option?

Comment: You never adequately explained what you are trying to accomplish, you didn't provide sample data, and you have not explained what is not working, so I don't have suggestions for improvement. Perhaps someone else can help

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function by creating a new query called, say, "fTableEnsureColumns" with code of:

```cs
let
  fAddNullColumn = (t as table, c as text) as table => Table.AddColumn(
    t,
    c,
    each null
  ),
  // curried version
  f2 = (ColumnNames as list)
   => (t as table)
   => List.Accumulate(
    // Missing columns
    List.RemoveItems(
      Table.ColumnNames(t),
      ColumnNames
    ),
    t,
    fAddNullColumn
  )
in
  // wrapper so the curyying is optional
  (ColumnNames as list, optional t as table) =>
  if t is null then
    // Only one argument. Return function expecting the second argument
    f2(ColumnNames)
  else
    // Both arguments given
    f2(ColumnNames)(t)
```

Currying is, instead of making a function that takes two parameters, making a single-parameter function that returns a function that takes the next parameter. It's a little strange, but I like to make reusable functions and this is something you can copy and use anywhere you might need it in the future, and the ability to use this as a curried function (calling `fTableEnsureColumn(columns)(table)`) makes this even more reusable.

For example, if you have a query called "RequiredColumns" that's equivalent to...

```cs
{"Source.Name", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Email","N_de_Documento__c","MobilePhone", "Tipo de Tarjeta","MailingStreet", "MailingPostalCode",  "MailingCity", "Provincia","Descripci_n_Fuente__c","Medio_Campa_a__c", "Campaña","Contenido_Campa_a__c", "ID Entrada", "Fecha_Ingreso__c","Numero de Tarjeta","Monto_Donacion__c","Vencimiento__c","Fuente__c"}
```

... then you can make a query called "fEnsureRequiredColumns" that is simply

```cs
fTableEnsureColumns(RequiredColumns)
```

and then you can make sure your tables have the columns needed by add missing columns via `fEnsureRequiredColumns{#"Your table here")` per table u need it for and using the resulting tables instead.

Of course, this assumes that null column values won't break your code, but that shouldn't be too hard to use if-thrn or try-otherwise to deal with that issue if it comes up.